# ERROR in Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js)

Tags: angular

When I run `ng build --prod` get this error. It can serve without error but it can't build. I relay tied with that

```
ERROR in Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):       
TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
    at normalizeBackSlashDirection (C:\project\tea supply chain mangement system\test2\node_modules\webpack\lib\RequestShortener.js:16:17)  
    at new RequestShortener (C:\project\tea supply chain mangement system\test2\node_modules\webpack\lib\RequestShortener.js:26:15)
    at new Compiler (C:\project\tea supply chain mangement system\test2\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:195:27)
    at Compiler.createChildCompiler (C:\project\tea supply chain mangement system\test2\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:548:25)        
    at Compilation.createChildCompiler (C:\project\tea supply chain mangement system\test2\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:2100:24) 
    at Object.pitch (C:\project\tea supply chain mangement system\test2\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\mini-css-extract-plugin\dist\loader.js:89:43)
```

My dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
  "@agm/core": "^1.1.0",
    "@angular/animations": "8.2.14",
    "@angular/cdk": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/common": "8.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler": "8.2.14",
    "@angular/core": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/http": "^7.2.15",
    "@angular/material": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/router": "8.2.14",
       ....
    "web3": "^1.2.4",
    "zone.js": "0.9.1"   
},   
   "devDependencies": {  
   "@angular-builders/custom-webpack": "^8.4.1",
    "@angular-builders/dev-server": "^7.3.1",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.803.21",
    "@angular-devkit/architect": "^0.803.21",
    "@angular/cli": "^8.3.21",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/language-service": "8.2.14",
    .....
  }
```

How to solve this error?

Comment: Why are you using v7 of the Angular CDK which is intended for applications using Angular v7, instead of updating to v8 of the Angular CDK?

Comment: i update it to v8 but it not helpful

Comment: You should also update the other Angular dependencies that are targeting v7 of the Angular framework.

Comment: i update all dependencies one by one . but it get same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in my case some css not work properly that's why get this error.it found when i check one by one. because this error hidden other errors.

Answer (score 2):

The discussion at https://github.com/webpack-contrib/mini-css-extract-plugin/issues/186 includes a statement that this error occurs when any component has a styleUrls property whose array value has a length greater than 1.

I verified this in an application where reducing the value of this property to an array of length 1 made the error disappear.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error because I've made a mistake of putting "" is styles list in angular.json file. I wanted to add css file and started typing but I made it the other way and I left this "" there.

```
"styles": [
  "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
  "src/styles.css",
  "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
  "" /* <--- this line breaks everything */
],
```